# Route design for Travelling Salesperson

Tags: software-recommendations, routing, travelling-salesman

I need a GIS-based solution that helps to identify the sales route of a salesperson. In a given situation, I have 500k POS/point of sales throughout the country. To server those 500k POS there are 100 Dealers. The dealer’s designated area is very well demarcated with a specific Dealer point. So there are more or less than 5k POS for each Dealer. I have already the longitude and latitude of every POS and Dealer’s office. I have full road data in GIS format. I have all the routing services installed in my system like OSRM, Valhalla, and Grasshopper. I have all the necessary software like ArcGIS Desktop and QGIS. I have also a PostgreSQL database with PostGIS. Now what do I want?
I want to create the best route for salespersons where the salesperson

1. Starts from Dealer Office Point and again after serving POS will go
   back to Dealer Office.
2. Each salesperson can not visit more than 50
   POS.

Now I need to know which suit of software can solve this problem efficiently.

Comment: You've got your data and software, now what have you tried and where are you stuck? If you want a step-by-step guide to 'travelling salesperson' it's not the simple question-answer format that is required on this site, if you want a comparison between paid and free GIS applications that falls under 'software reccomendations' and is also off topic for this site. As it stands your request is too broad, please focus on a specific problem that can have an answer  that doen't read like 'War and Peace'.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks for your comment. I know It is a broad topic. Actually, I want to get an answer like what will be my approach. I do not want any solution. If I can get a starting point of the solution that will be enough. After that I can implement by myself

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/solving-geographic-travelling-salesman-problems-using-python-e57284b14cd7 looks like a starting point. I'm sure there are many more on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclosure: I work for Esri and this is not my area of interest.

I think you have 2 'major' problems. The first is to identify the territory for each dealer--check for location/allocation. It might be called something different--that's the term I learned 20+ years ago).

Further divide the Dealer territories into salesperson territories.

Finally, you need to define routes for the salesperson territories which is now the traveling salesperson problem.